# Ubuntu: ubuntu error when find etc/profile

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu, locale, kali

***Questions***: I just get stuck in the loading page with error showing. It shows me that line-2 have some errors. Therefore, i kept being locked out.

I have tried

```
apt upgrade
apt update
apt reinstall base-files
apt autoremove
```

Wanting : But it doesnt work. Is there someone who can explain to me why this happens and how can i log in my computer?

Comment: Please clarify what OS/release you're using.  FYI: Kali in Debian & Ubuntu refers to a drawing program, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kali&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kali so how does that relate?  (Kali != Kali Linux)  your tags make little sense

Answer (score 0):

When logging in to Ubuntu on Xorg, there is code to prevent that particular error. Consequently I suppose you are trying to log in to a wayland session.

Try to log in to "Ubuntu on Xorg" instead. If that succeeds, you can then investigate `/etc/profile`.

*Edit:*

I assumed you were talking about Ubuntu. Now I see that you have tagged some flavors. The code I was talking about is present in LightDM too, and if I recall correctly, Xubuntu's default display manager is LightDM, while Kubuntu and Lubuntu use some other DM.